# Android TabLayout could not be instantiated

Tags: java, android, xml

i have problem with android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.
I want to add it to my activity_main.xml and then i have error:

> Rendering Problems
>     The following classes could not be instantiated:
>    - android.support.design.widget.TabLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

I have latest API24 , my gradle file looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.zawadeusz.yahooweatherapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 15
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
//compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0"
compile "com.android.support:design:24.0.0"
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: "Rendering error" usually means that Android Studio's drag-and-drop GUI builder is having issues again. Try changing the API level drop-down in the GUI builder's toolbar -- this is probably set to 24 or 23 for you.

Comment: Nothings changed...